# How to update an existing test model and controller for Neo4j in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, neo4j

I have a Rails application which was migrated recently to Neo4j technology. Now I'm trying to adapt or update the existing testing files to this new technology. However, I had some difficulties and many fails. What I need is to understand the code I will share below. How to change that code to be suitable for Neo4j. I need a reference as online I could not find any good one. In the specific case I'm sharing I understood the destroy or delete is not working and also my error is that the expected result does not match.

This is the error I have from running rspec:

```
Failure/Error: expect(result).to eq(expected)

       expected: {:data=>[{:study_version_id=>nil, :cid=>"X1", :namespace=>"http://www.example.com", :property=>"quest...le.com", :property=>"enabled", :study_value=>"true", :default_value=>"true", :datatype=>"boolean"}]}
            got: {:data=>[{:amendment=>{:created_at=>"2017-11-14T13:19:09.000+00:00", :updated_at=>"2017-11-14T13:19:0...true", :default_value=>"true", :datatype=>"boolean", :id=>"fa97a13f-3c2a-4391-80c0-6d61250e7367"}}]}
```

Below my controller_spec and model_spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe AmendmentsController, type: :controller do

  include UserAccountHelpers
  include FileHelpers
  include JsonHelpers

  def sub_dir
    return "controllers"
  end

  describe "Edit Access" do

    before :all do
      Amendment.delete_all
      a = Amendment.create(cid: "X1", namespace:  "http://www.example.com", property: "question",
        study_value: "ADEF", default_value: "A1", datatype: "string")
      a = Amendment.create(cid: "X1", namespace:  "http://www.example.com", property: "enabled",
        study_value: "true", default_value: "true", datatype: "boolean")
      a = Amendment.create(cid: "Y1", namespace:  "http://www.example.com", property: "enabled",
        study_value: "false", default_value: "true", datatype: "boolean")
      ua_create
    end

    after :all do
      Amendment.delete_all
      ua_destroy
    end

    before :each do
      login_with_edit_access
    end

    after :each do
    end

    it "finds amendments for a given item" do
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
      get :find, {amendment: {cid: "X1", namespace: "http://www.example.com"}}
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
      result = remove_id_and_timestamps(response)
    #write_yaml_file(result, sub_dir, "amendments_controller_find_1.txt")
      expected = read_yaml_file(sub_dir, "amendments_controller_find_1.txt")
      expect(result).to eq(expected)
    end

    it "finds amendments for a given item, none present" do
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
      get :find, {amendment: {cid: "X11", namespace: "http://www.example.com"}}
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
    #write_text_file(response.body, sub_dir, "amendments_controller_find_2.txt")
      expected = read_text_file(sub_dir, "amendments_controller_find_2.txt")
      expect(response.body).to eq(expected)
    end

    it "creates an amendment" do
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
      post :create, {amendment: {cid: "X11", namespace: "http://www.example.com", property: "question",
        study_value: "SSS", default_value: "AAA", datatype: "string"}}
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
    end

    it "updates an amendment" do
      a = Amendment.create(cid: "X11", namespace:  "http://www.example.com", property: "question",
        study_value: "ADEF", default_value: "A1", datatype: "string")
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
      put :update, {id: a.id, amendment: {property: "question", 
        study_value: "SSS", default_value: "AAA", datatype: "string"}}
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
    #write_text_file(response.body, sub_dir, "amendments_controller_create_1.txt")
      expected = read_text_file(sub_dir, "amendments_controller_create_1.txt")
      expect(response.body).to eq(expected)
    end

    it "destroys an amendment" do
      a = Amendment.create(cid: "X11", namespace:  "http://www.example.com", property: "question", 
        study_value: "ADEF", default_value: "A1", datatype: "string")
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
      delete :destroy, {id: a.id}
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
    end

  end

  describe "Unauthorized User" do

    it "find" do
      get :find
      expect(response).to redirect_to("/users/sign_in")
    end

    it "create" do
      post :create
      expect(response).to redirect_to("/users/sign_in")
    end

    it 'update' do
      put :update, {id: 1}
      expect(response).to redirect_to("/users/sign_in")
    end

    it 'destroy' do
      delete :destroy, {id: 1}
      expect(response).to redirect_to("/users/sign_in")
    end

  end

end

# MODEL 
require 'rails_helper'

describe Amendment do

  before :each do
    Amendment.(&:destroy)
  end

  after :each do
    Amendment.(&:destroy)
  end

  it "serializes the amendmemt as a hash" do
    amendment = Amendment.create(cid: "XXX", namespace:  "http://ww.example.com", property: "question",
      study_value: "ADEF", default_value: "A", datatype: "string")
        result = amendment.to_hash
        expected = 
        { 
            cid: "XXX", 
            namespace: "http://ww.example.com", 
            property: "question", 
            study_value: "ADEF",
      default_value: "A",
      datatype: "string"
        }
    expect(result).to eq(expected)
  end

end
```

Comment: Using `before :all` and `after :all` is a fragile construct which will cause issues when the specs are run in a random order. You want to reset the DB state before each example.

Comment: @max could you please show me an example of what I should do? because I stuck with this thanks

Comment: @jakub you want a different context for each of your test. In that case, you don't have to use the `before` block but just setup the data needed for the test at the beginning of it, like you did for the `updates an amendment` test. Tests are: setup, exercise, verify and then teardown (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/four-phase-test). You only need to define a `before`/`after` block if you need to share data between your tests or if several of them need the same data setup

Comment: Yes I understood that but still cannot figure out how to make this test to work